# VB6 / VB.NET make a .dll to be used only by a specific program

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6

I'm making a .dll from VB6, that will be used by a VB.NET program.
Since I want that this .dll will be used ONLY by my software, my question is: 
is there a way from my VB6 .dll to check if its methods are called by my software and not anything else? I don't know, maybe I can sign my application and check in some way from VB6 if it's called by an application with that sign.

Anyone know a solution for it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are looking at licensing  http://www.bing.com/search?q=licencing+a+dll&form=OSDSRC

Comment: No I'm not looking at license, and the .DLL must be written in VB6. Please read my question before -vote it

Comment: @FeFe Licensing will restrict the use of your dll to the applications that you permit. There is no other way that I know of to restrict the use of a dll.

Comment: What is so important about your DLL that it mustn't be used by a third party?

Comment: Will the DLL be used by any more of your programs? If not, the  just build the code into your VB6 app. I would say write th3 ehole thing in .Net and obfuscate te0he code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter that will accept a password. Pass the password in method calls.

Use an obfuscator to protect the application code and the password.

Comment: So anyone that decompile my vb.net program can get the password and use the .dll

Comment: What is so important about the DLL that you don't want it used by another program?